# Update query in sql with duplicate records

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1062

I have a table(millions of record)  with unique index for (dataid,url). The table looks like this:

```
id  dataid url
1   230    https://www.example.com/123
3   230    http://example.com/123
```

I'm unable to run the query

```
UPDATE table_name SET url = REPLACE(url, 'http://', 'https://www.')
```

as there are duplicates and violation of unique key constraint. In such a case, i want to delete the record with the largest 'id' value. How do I go about this?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Different products, similar SQL, but some differences.

Comment: Can you add some more sample data, and the expected result? Only two rows now, with same dataid.

Comment: replacing a url that is http and www prefixed, e.g. `http://www.abc.de` will result in `https://www.www.abc.de` ... just to have it in mind. First check if you have this occurrences and if they exist then change all `http://www.` to `http://` and then complete as you wish with `https://www.` replacemenet.

Comment: @jarlh MySQL... I wasnt able to add many links.. 
id  dataid url
1   230    https://www.example.com/123
3   230    http://example.com/123
4   231     http://example.com/1234

Expected Output
id  dataid url
1   230    https://www.example.com/123
4   231    https://www.example.com/1234

Comment: @MrSimpleMind Thanks for the point. But fortunately no such entries in the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete 
    from table a 
    join table b on a.dataid = b.dataid 
where 
    a.dataid = 230 and a.id > b.id;
```

try it out

Answer (score 0):

This will find out the row that should be deleted

```
select max(id), REPLACE(url, 'http://', 'https://www.') as url from table
group by REPLACE(url, 'http://', 'https://www.') 
having count(*)>1
```

This will delete them

```
delete t1 from table as t1 inner join
(
select max(id), REPLACE(url, 'http://', 'https://www.') as url from table
group by REPLACE(url, 'http://', 'https://www.') 
having count(*)>1
) as t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

Now update your data

```
UPDATE table_name SET url = REPLACE(url, 'http://', 'https://www.')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete tst
where id in (select max(id)
             from tst
             group by dataid, REPLACE(url, 'http://', 'https://www.')
             having count(*) = 2);

UPDATE tst SET url = REPLACE(url, 'http://', 'https://www.');
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly you should delete duplicates. 
This query should help you:

```
delete from 
table_name 
where id in (
   select max(id)
   from table_name 
   group by REPLACE(url, 'http://', 'https://www.')
   having count(*) > 1
)
```